# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch ruby 1.8 without using spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rails-activerecord, ruby-1.8

I have models specs, controllers spec and request spec. When I run:

```
         rspec spec
```

models spec are run first, then request and then when controller specs are run the specs for the first controller are OK, but the next fail. But when I run only the controller specs they all pass. I am with rails 3.0.9, ruby 1.8, factory_girl 2.2.0. I have

```
        config.cache_classes = true
```

in test.rb and I can't change the version of ruby or factory_girl. Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**:

This is the error:

```
 96) UsersController reset_password: as non-master_admin: does not reset a user's password
 Failure/Error: let!(:user) { Factory(:admin_user) }
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   AdminUser(#-630697398) expected, got MerchantUser(#-629918188)
 # ./app/models/activity.rb:33:in `log'
 # ./config/initializers/add_activity_logging.rb:8:in `_callback_after_759'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:8
```

in spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:8:

```
let!(:user) { Factory(:admin_user) }
```

in activity.rb:33:

```
  create(:user => user, :title => title, :changeable_id => changeable.id,
      :changeable_type => changeable.class.to_s, :data => attributes)
```

also there is:

```
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'AdminUser'
```

in the class AdminUser there isn't has_many activities but when I tried to add it I couldn't add it correctly I guess. 
Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**:
   AdminUser and MerchantUser are descendants of User

**POSIBLE FIX**
   The line that gave error was actually:

```
   admin_user = Factory(:tech_admin)
```

I replaced it with:

```
  admin_user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:tech_admin)
```

This way the file activity.rb is not reached

**FINAL FIX**
Apparently the problem was with Factory(:reseller). I replaced it with FactoryGirl.create(:reseller) and it everything work. Though now I am wondering and searching what is the difference between the two uses

Comment: We really can’t say much without the exact command line calls you’re using, and the error messages that are displayed.  Possibly also the code of the controller spec that’s failing.

Comment: It looks like user is actually a MerchantUser object, not AdminUser when the spec is run.  Can you check that?

Comment: Yes. I am sure I am using factory for AdminUser

Comment: But it seems to be creating a MerchantUser.  Can you check the class of user in the spec?  Add "puts user.class" in the test case, or something like that.

Comment: I add it and now I am waiting for execution of all test. It is interesting that the test never fails when he is run alone but fails when he is run with all other.

Comment: I understand that, but it’s very hard to diagnose without having access to the full code.  Anyway, glad you very able to fix the problem.